# kotlinでセンサーの値を一定時間で定期的に取得したい

Tags: android, kotlin

androidアプリをkotlinを利用して作成しており、センサー情報を一定間隔（１０秒間隔）で取得したいですが、やり方がわからず、以下のソースコードにあります、sensorManager.registerListener(this, mSensor, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_UI)　を sensorManager.registerListener(this, mSensor, 10000000)としてみましたが取得間隔は変わりませんでした。

間隔を変更する事は可能でしょうか？
よろしくお願いします。

```
val sensorManager: SensorManager = getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE) as SensorManager
sensors = sensorManager.getSensorList(Sensor.TYPE_ALL)
if (sensors.size > 0) {
    for (i in 0..sensors.size-1) {
        val mSensor: Sensor = sensors.get(i);
        sensorManager.registerListener(this, mSensor, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_UI)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

すいません、実際に試したわけではないのですが。
registerListenerの第4引数maxReportLatencyUsを10秒にしてみたらどうでしょうか？

- https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/SensorManager#registerListener(android.hardware.SensorEventListener,%20android.hardware.Sensor,%20int,%20int)
- http://mslabo.sakura.ne.jp/WordPress/make/processing%E3%80%80%E9%80%86%E5%BC%95%E3%81%8D%E3%83%AA%E3%83%95%E3%82%A1%E3%83%AC%E3%83%B3%E3%82%B9/%E7%85%A7%E5%BA%A6%E3%82%BB%E3%83%B3%E3%82%B5%E3%83%BC%E3%82%92%E4%BD%BF%E3%81%86%E3%81%AB%E3%81%AF%EF%BC%88androidmode%E7%B7%A8%EF%BC%89/

上手くいかない場合はアプリ側でなんとかした方がいいかもしれませんね。
coroutinesライブラリでdebounceが使用できるので、こちらで10秒間隔に束ねるとか。

- https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.flow/debounce.html

Comment: ありがとう御座いました。
教えて頂きました、registerListenerの第4引数maxReportLatencyUsを設置してみましたが上手くいかず、タイマーで取得する様にしました。